# Lambda@Edge function with Nodejs return 502 ERROR The Lambda function returned an invalid entry in the headers object

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I'm trying Lambda@Edge with this simple function.

```
let express = require('express');
let serverless = require("serverless-http");
let app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello World`);
});
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.disable("content-length");
app.disable("etag");
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

When i test the lambda function it works with this result:

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"headers": {
"content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
"content-length": "189"
},
"isBase64Encoded": false,
"body": "Hello World  "
}
```

When i deploy at the edge i see this error:

[Error 502](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPACw.png)

On cloudwatch
`ERROR Validation error: The Lambda function returned an invalid entry in the headers object, each header entry in the headers object must be an array, header : content-type is not an array.`

[According to this:](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-restrictions.html) the problem in in the header, can you help me to find where is in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/running-express-applications-on-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/

Not sure if express directly works with lambda, they have their own flavour of it called aws-serverless-express. Despite the test returning a 200 initially, once deployed to Lambda@Edge, the test fails.